# Another Straightforward 4-letters Crossword?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, crosswords

<sub>*This is an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7062/28719).*</sub>

---

[image]

**Across**
4. "___ and on"
5. "La ___" light
6. Aside from it
8. Diagonal
10. Firefly
12. Clothes shop
14. Supersede
16. -ism or -y
18. Area in Da Nang
21. "___ many times do..."
22. Dad and son
23. From readers

**Down**
1. Strange word
2. "Diana" son
3. Analyze
5. (lit.) Fish
7. Ideal closed
9. "I Agree" (Sumo)
11. Rope's end
13. "These are ___ times"
15. "Perry Mason"?
17. Should be
19. Aid of a sort
20. An angry act

**The final answer** will be a 4-words phrase.

Comment: [grid-deduction] tag is added as part of a hint.

Comment: This was a very nice puzzle! I'm impressed with how well the clues worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The trick to this puzzle is that

> the clues are completely unsolvable!

So what do you do?

> You might start to notice some repetitions - `"These are ___ times"`, and `"___ many times do..."`, for instance. Or maybe you notice that "son" ends both `Dad and son` and `"Perry Mason"?`.
>
>  So, instead of entering answers into the grid, you enter *the clues* into the grid! Some letters have to be squeezed into the same cell, but there is a unique way to do this.

The filled grid:

> [image]

And now, for the final answer,

> since this is a "4-letters crossword"< look at all the cells that have exactly four letters. Top to bottom, these spell out the answer: **STRAIGHT FROM THE SHOULDERS**, which is an expression meaning "honest" or "straightforward".

Comment: Ah, just when I thought this straightforward puzzle isn't that straightforward (and afraid that this wouldn't be solved in a long time.) Great job and very well done! :)